# Do I need to create these many classes for this android app?

Tags: android-layout

I am an absolute beginner at programming so I just want to make sure I am doing this right or if there is an easier way. basically the app I am creating is a school app that will list all courses needed for different majors.

So opening screen has two buttons undergrad and grad. The next screen would list all majors for either grad or undergrad, which ever one the user chose, then say a person clicked accounting it would then list all courses for accounting major. My question is do I need to create a seperate class for each course and major?? Below is the code I have been doing.

```
       package Class.Review;

import Class.Review.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ClassReviewActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button Undergrad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BUNGrad);
    Undergrad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = 
                    new Intent(view.getContext(),        undergrad.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Then say the user clicked undergrad i created another class**

```
     package Class.Review;

import Class.Review.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;


public class undergrad extends Activity  {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.undergrad);


setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent replyIntent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, replyIntent);
    finish();
}
});
}

private void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub




Button Accounting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Accounting);
Accounting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent myIntent = 
            new Intent(view.getContext(), accounting.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
}
 });
}
}
```

**Then choice a specific course within Accounting**

```
    package Class.Review;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class accReview extends Activity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.accreview);

    setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent replyIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, replyIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

private void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Button review = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reviews);
review.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent myIntent = 
                new Intent(view.getContext(), fundReview.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
});
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need different functionality for each course, you're probably better of using a single Course class with a few fields containing course name (String), max number of students (some integer type), maybe a Professor object, or whatever you need to describe the course. You don't want to rewrite, recompile and redistribute the code each time you want to add, remove or rename a course, do you?

Also, this doesn't just apply to this specific case, this question has probably been asked tons of times before.